# Nested HTML Ordered List starting with 1.1

Tags: html, html-lists

(Warning: I am relatively new to HTML coding...)

I want my nested HTML ordered list to look like the following:

```
1.1 Authorization and Authentication
    1.1.1   Bla Blaa Bla
    1.1.2   More bla bla
    1.1.3   almost Final Bla bla bla            
       A    detail 1            
       B    detail 2            
       C    detail 3
    1.1.4   Final Bla
    
1.2 Acceptable Use
    1.2.1   Do this
    1.2.3   Do that
```

Note that I am starting with 1.1 instead of 1.  Is this possible? From my research, I need a css file to put some code in that will give me the 1.2.3 numbering system.  Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

Frank

Answer (score 0):

You can actually put whatever you want before list items! If you are generating the html via JavaScript (or modifying it via JavaScript), then you could do something like this:

```css
li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(value);
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li value="test :)">First</li>
  <li value="1.1">Second</li>
  <li value="2.2.2">Third</li>
</ol>
```